# Substitute method parameter with a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have some html files with javascript functions like this

```
<!-- some content -->
<div conmousedown="My_Function('FirstParamterThatCanBeAnything', '')">
<!-- some content -->
</div>
<!-- some content -->
```

I would like to be able to use a substitution ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) 
to set the second parameter without changing the rest :

```
<!-- some content -->
<div conmousedown="My_Function('FirstParamterThatCanBeAnything', 'SOMENEWVALUE')">
<!-- some content -->
</div>
<!-- some content -->
```

the first parameter is an url with random parameters, it's never the same

can someone help me finding a regular expression ?

Comment: yes, but I'm stuck with the regular expressions, I tried  (MyFunction\([^)]+)?([^)]+,''\)) for the regex and $1 for the replacement but it's not that

Comment: Ok, there are a couple of issues there. You don't have an underscore in the function name and I think there are some backslashes missing (unless the site ate them in comments, use backticks to format code in comments). Well, after that, I just rewrote another regex and came up with [this](http://regex101.com/r/tS1nU5). What's happening is there are 2 parts to be captured: one before the first `'` of the 2nd param, and the part after that, so you actually need a replace of `$1SOMEVALUE$2`. I added a little something to the regex as well, just in case you don't only have single quoted strings.

Comment: It's perfect! thank you so much ! and the http://regex101.com/ website is really useful

Comment: Just a precision : for the replace I used $1SOMEVALUE$2) (I added a ')' at the end)

Comment: Well, I used the second capture group for the quotes, so in the end, you will use `$3` instead of `$2` :) I wanted to add that but the comment was almost to the character limit! I put a answer below so you can mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, here's the regex I propose:

```
(My_Function\((?:[^,']+|("|')(?:(?!\2).)*\2), ')('\))
```

Breakdown:

```
(                 # Open 1st Capture group
  My_Function\(   # Match My_Function(
  (?:
    [^,']+        # Match any non comma/quote characters (for numeric param)
  |               # Or
    ("|')         # A quote stored in 2nd Capture group
    (?:(?!\2).)*  # Any character except the quote that matched
    \2            # The quote that matched
  )
  , '             # Match a comma, a space and a single quote
)                 # End 1st Capture group
(                 # Open 3rd Capture group
'\)               # Match single quote and )
)                 # Close 2nd Capture group
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/tS1nU5#pcre)

Implementing that in C# will be something a bit like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(My_Function\((?:[^,']+|(""|')(?:(?!\2).)*\2), ')('\))");
str = regex.Replace(text, "$1SOMENEWVALUE$3");
```

Where `text` contains the page.